# How do I build an existing React-native ios app in android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an iOS app, written in React Native.  I can build the iOS app in XCode, deploy it etc. but mainly by following a list of steps - I don't really know what I'm actually doing.

Now I'd like to build it for Android, but I'm not sure where to start. For iOS I do `npm install` and `pod install`, but I don't have a `Podfile` for the `android` directory - do I just copy it across from the `ios` one?

I've looked online, but everything I've come across is about creating a project from scratch, not opening an existing project.  Can someone with more experience advise me on where to start?

My directory structure is:

my_app >
App.js
app.json
index.js
package.json
node_modules > (generated by npm install)
src > (all my source code)
ios > Podfile
Pods > (generated by pod install)
MyApp.xcodeproj
MyApp.xcworkspace
MyApp > (some .h, .m and .entitlements files)
android > build.gradle
gradle.properties
app > (contains src, build etc)
gradle > (contains wrapper)
local.properties
settings.gradle

Comment: https://medium.com/@nevin_61019/creating-and-opening-your-react-native-project-in-android-studio-for-mac-db9b529cca28 check if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! That's enough to get me started!